# TypeError: element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function in Server Side Rendering Angular 5

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I got this error in server side rendering with using "@swimlane/ngx-datatable". I follow this [link](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/docs/universal/server-side-rendering.md) but not work ,I provide this following two service in `root.module.server.ts` and also try in which independent module where use data table.

When run this on browser there is everything fine.Anyone know how to resolve this.thanks.

```
ERROR TypeError: element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at DimensionsHelper.getDimensions (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:233933:24)    at DatatableComponent.recalculateDims (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:254801:42)
    at DatatableComponent.recalculate (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:254764:14)    at DatatableComponent.set [as rows] (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:254406:18)
    at updateProp (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:12921:37)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveDynamic (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:12692:23)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeDynamic (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:14220:20)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:14144:16)
    at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:14865:5)
    at Object.updateDirectives (E:\ecap3\ecap3-webclient-selectnetwork\dist\server.js:285222:53720)
```

Comment: can you do DOM manipulation in server-side rendering ? in angular 2 and 4 that was not possible

Comment: I use https://github.com/fgnass/domino for basic dom manipulation e.g: window,document etc

Comment: Show you code maybe

Comment: show `root.module.server.ts` for instance

Comment: Same error in my case.

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { App } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [ App ],
})
export class AppServerModule {}

Comment: @ShamimHossain https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/docs/universal/server-side-rendering.md , can you see this link? I tried but fail.